# 4-5 column dropdown center with page

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXq8n.png) So I have a 4 column dropdown for a site that I am doing, but the problem is that it always drops to the right and gets pushed off the screen. I have tried to search through the other answers about dropdown centering but cannot get any of them to work. I have included the code that all the instances of the dropdown menu appears.

first set

```
<script>
$(function() {
  if ('WebkitColumnCount' in document.body.style || 'MozColumnCount' in document.body.style || 'OColumnCount' in document.body.style || 'MsColumnCount' in document.body.style || 'columnCount' in document.body.style) {
    $('ul.dropdown').filter(function() {
      return $(this).find('li').size() > 16
    }).addClass('two-column');
  }
});
</script>

<style>
.two-column {
-moz-column-count:4;
-webkit-column-count:4;
-o-column-count:4;
column-count:4;
-moz-column-gap:0px;
-webkit-column-gap:0px;
-o-column-gap:0px;
column-gap:0px;


}
```

second set

```
 {% for link in linklists.main-menu.links %}
    {% assign child_list_handle = link.title | handleize %}
    {% if linklists[child_list_handle].links != blank %}

      <li class="site-nav--has-dropdown{% if link.active %} site-nav--active{% endif %}" aria-haspopup="true">
        <a href="{{ link.url }}">
          {{ link.title }}
          <span class="icon-fallback-text">
            <span class="icon icon-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </span>
        </a>

        <ul class="site-nav--dropdown">
          <ul class = "dropdown"  style="white">
          {% for childlink in linklists[child_list_handle].links %}
            <li {% if childlink.active %}class="site-nav--active"{% endif %}><a href="{{ childlink.url }}">{{ childlink.title | escape }}</a></li>
          {% endfor %}

          </ul>
        </ul>        
      </li>
```

from css

```
/*================ Dropdowns ================*/
.icon-arrow-down {
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.site-nav--dropdown {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;

}

.site-nav--dropdown .icon-arrow-down {
  display: none !important;

}

/*================ Large screen dropdown styles ================*/
@include at-query ($min, $large) {
  .site-nav--dropdown {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    border: 1px solid $colorBorder;
    background-color: $colorBody;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 20;
    @include transition(all 150ms);
    font-size: 15px;

    .no-touch .site-nav--has-dropdown:hover &,
    .site-nav--has-dropdown.nav-hover &,
    .nav-focus + &,
    .show-dropdown & {
      opacity: 1;
      box-shadow: 0 5px 40px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
      visibility: visible;
      @include transition(all 90ms);
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
      text-align: center;
    }


    a {
      color: white;
      text-transform: none;
      padding: $gutter/100 $gutter*1.5 $gutter/100 $gutter/98;

      &:hover,
      &:active,
      &:focus {
        color: darken($colorPrimary, 10%);

      }

      &:focus {
        background-color: darken($colorBody, 5%);
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: can you show working fiddle or snippet

Comment: are you wanting like a screen shot of the issue that is going on, or what are you asking about "working fiddle or snippet"

Comment: that is fine can you show one